# Can I style individual elements of a <FormattedDate />?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-intl

I'm using **FormattedDate** to display the time, and I was wondering If I could style every individual part of the time.
I managed to style the hour and minutes but what about the "AM" && "PM".

My goal is to have something similar the attached image

[image]

Comment: Don't think so. That format is not really locale friendly anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I did some research, and posted a question as an issue on the github repo of **react-intl**
Here is the answer that I got:

```
"This is not currently possible, but this is the exact use-case for the 
formatToParts() API that we standardized as part of JavaScript! 
Eventually we'll use this API directly within React Intl."
```

[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat/formatToParts](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat/formatToParts)

Alternative solution:

During my research I found another interesting NPM module called [DateFormat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dateformat)
The tool is pretty flexible, and I was able to get the desired result by styling every single element of a date